# Update android app in Google play

Tags: android

Can we upload new Hybrid build with using the existing native app private key in the Google play?.

The new hybrid build will be available for users as a update of their existing native app or  users have to download it as a new app.

If we will upload the new build using the different package name, then will we able to upload the build as update for existing build or it will be treated as a new app.

If we downgrade the app from hybrid to native app then will we able to upload the new native app build as update of existing app or it will be treated as a separate build.

---

Answer (score 2):

To update app in Play Store you need to use the same package name and sign your apk file with the same keystore. You can't release two applications with same package name! If you want to upload for example a beta public test version of your app you will need to upload it with new package name, but the users which already have your application installed won't receive any alerts, because it will be a separate app. It depends on what you exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: If i upgrade my app from Native to Hybrid and package name and singing key remains the same. Will i able to upload the app as an update to my existing app.

Comment: If you use the same package name and sign your app with the same keystore you will be able to update your app, doesn't matter what you used for building the new version. Just remember to change your version code and version name. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

**1. Update Existing App**

- If you want to update existing app and wants existing user's to receive as an update then you must sign your application with same key and package name must be same. You need to increase the version code and version name in manifest.

**2. Launch New App**

- If you want to launch it as new app you need to use unique package name and key can be same. It will be treated as new app.

I hope its clear to you.